# Disabling Redis cache on fail in NestJS

Tags: node.js, caching, server, redis, nestjs

I run a NestJS server, where I use Redis for caching. Thats how I initialize it:

```
import { CacheModule, Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import * as redisStore from "cache-manager-redis-store";

@Module({
imports: [
    CacheModule.register({
      store: redisStore,
      isGlobal: true,
      host: env.REDIS_HOST,
      port: env.REDIS_PORT,
      password: envVar.REDIS_ACCESS_KEY,
      tls: {
        host: env.REDIS_HOST,
      },
      ttl: 1800,
    })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

I access the cache in 2 ways throughout the project:

using `CacheInterceptor`:

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  UseInterceptors,
  CacheInterceptor
} from "@nestjs/common";

@Controller()
@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  findAll(): string[] {
    return [];
  }
}
```

using `cache.wrap`:

```
import {
  Body,
  CACHE_MANAGER,
  Controller,
  Inject,
  Post,
} from "@nestjs/common";
import { Cache } from "cache-manager";

@Controller("items")
export class ItemsController {
  constructor(
    private itemsService: ItemsService,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache
  ) {}

  @Post("id")
  async getItemById(
    @Body("id") id: number,
  ) {
      return await this.cacheManager.wrap(`item-${id}`, () =>
        this.itemsService.getItem(code)
      );
  }
}
```

The problem is, when the redis sevice is down for some reason, the error is fatal and the server crashes. I want the server to keep on working, without caching. That is the current error:

[image: error]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this is how I've handled it. Override the constructor to setup a listener on the `error` and `ready` events. Use those to set a flag in the interceptor, which is checked in `intercept`, that has be overridden. If the cache is unavailable, just call `next.handle()`. If the cache *is* available, pass off to the superclass.

```js
import { CacheInterceptor, CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  Inject,
  Injectable,
  Logger,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpCacheInterceptor extends CacheInterceptor {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(HttpCacheInterceptor.name);


  private isAvailable = true;

  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) protected readonly cacheManager: any,
    protected readonly reflector: Reflector
  ) {
    super(cacheManager, reflector);
    this.checkAvailability();
  }

  checkAvailability() {
    const client = this.cacheManager.store.getClient();
    client.on('error', (err: any) => {
      this.logger.error(`cache: failed to connect: ${err}`);
      this.isAvailable = false;
    });
    client.on('ready', () => {
      this.logger.log('cache: ready');
      this.isAvailable = true;
    });
  }

  async intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler
  ): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    this.logger.debug(`isAvailable=${this.isAvailable}`);
    if (this.isAvailable) {
      this.logger.debug('cache: cache interceptor is handling the response');
      return super.intercept(context, next);
    }
    this.logger.error('cache: unavailable');
    return next.handle();
  }

}
```